# ajax timer works only every second time modal is loaded

Tags: jquery, ajax, modal-dialog, setinterval

I'm creating website based on bootstrap for my teacher as a small project, and i have problem with my timer. So this website is built with tiles which, when clicked, trigger ajax function which fills modal, and at the end modal shows up.
The problem is with timer in modal. It's working only every second time modal is showed. There is no errors in console or anything helpful.
This is my php outputing the modal:

```
echo "<div id='timer_out' onclick='timer_start()' style='font-size: calc(35px + 5vw); font-weight: bold;'>00:00:00:000</div>";
echo "<span>Podnieś spację, aby włączyć/wyłączyć timer</span>";
echo '
    <script>
        out=$("#timer_out");
        counter="";
        running=false;
        function timer_start(){
            if(running){
                running=false;
                clearInterval(counter);
                return;
            }
            running=true;
            time=0;
            start = new Date;

            counter=setInterval(function(){
                console.log("test")
                time=new Date - start;
                h=Math.floor(time/1000/60/24);
                min=Math.floor(time/1000/60-h*1000*60*24);
                sec=Math.floor(time/1000-min*60-h*1000*60*24);
                ms=Math.floor(time-sec*1000-min*60*1000-h*1000*60*24);
                if(h<10) h="0"+h;
                if(min<10) min="0"+min;
                if(sec<10) sec="0"+sec;
                if(ms<10) ms="00"+ms;
                else if(ms<100) ms="0"+ms;
                out.text(h+":"+min+":"+sec+":"+ms);
            }, 1);
        }
        function timer_stop(){
            running=false;
            clearInterval(counter);
        }
        document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){
            if (event.code!="Space") return;
            timer_start();
        });
        $("#mainModal").on("hide.bs.modal", function (e) {
            timer_stop();
        });
        $("#mainModal").on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {
            timer_stop();
        });
    </script>
';
```

I discovered that when I trigger a timer second time (so it's not working) function timer_start() fires up, but Interval is not created, so for me it's even more confusing :/

Here's my ajax if it's helpful for you:

```
modal_body=$(this).find('div.modal-body')
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'php/getModal.php',
  data: {
    id: '-3'
  }
}).done(function(returned){

    modal_body.html(returned);

}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
  alert('error'+'\n'+jqXHR+'\n'+textStatus+'\n'+errorThrown);
}).always(function(){
});
```

Even more interesting is that on phone, it works perfectly ヽ(。_°)ノ

Answer (score 0):

I reworked your code a bit, so it works in the fiddle. You can test it, no problems arise.

```js
out = $("#timer_out");
counter = "";
running = false;

document.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  if (!running) timer_start();
  else timer_stop();
});

function timer_start() {
  running = true;
  time = 0;
  start = new Date;

  counter = setInterval(function() {
    console.log("test")
    time = new Date - start;
    h = Math.floor(time / 1000 / 60 / 24);
    min = Math.floor(time / 1000 / 60 - h * 1000 * 60 * 24);
    sec = Math.floor(time / 1000 - min * 60 - h * 1000 * 60 * 24);
    ms = Math.floor(time - sec * 1000 - min * 60 * 1000 - h * 1000 * 60 * 24);
    if (h < 10) h = "0" + h;
    if (min < 10) min = "0" + min;
    if (sec < 10) sec = "0" + sec;
    if (ms < 10) ms = "00" + ms;
    else if (ms < 100) ms = "0" + ms;
    out.text(h + ":" + min + ":" + sec + ":" + ms);
  }, 1);
}

function timer_stop() {
  running = false;
  clearInterval(counter);
}
```

```css
.timer_out {
  font-size: calc(35px + 5vw);
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='timer_out' class="timer_out">00:00:00:000</div>
```

Does your problem show, if you rewrite it **without AJAX**?

Answer (score 0):

I FOUND THE PROBLEM!!!.
It turns out that browser are aggressively caching js events. So this code:

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){
    if (event.code!="Space") return;
    timer_start();
});
```

Is loaded to browser's cache whenever i download it with ajax, and at first time it's working fine, second it fires up, starts timer and then second loaded event fires up and turns it off, same for fourth, fifth and so on. How do i fixed that? Here:

```
pressed = new Array();
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    pressed[event.code] = false;
});
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){
    pressed[event.code] = true;
});

setInterval(function(){
    if (pressed["Space"]==true){
        pressed["Space"]=false;
        if (running) timer_stop();
        else timer_start();
    }
}, 50);
```

It's more advanced key handler. I will change it in my code so it won't fire up so many intervals.